# loading the python interpreter with a python script

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a windows application that I would like to launch some python scripts from. It is possible that the user will not have python installed.

Is there a way to package with my application the python interpreter in a way that I dont need the user to install it? The python script has minimal imports so I dont need everything brought over. Is there a way I can from my application load the interpreter into memory then somehow point the python script at it?

I looked a little bit at py2exe as a possability, I was curious if there was just a way to send a trimmed down intepreter with out compiling the python.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [cx_freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/). It can create executable python application. I would not use py2exe: it not supported now.

Answer (score 1):

http://portablepython.com/ 
Something like that. Make script in bash to link python scripts to this interpreter.